# Python Pandas - Slice DataFrame based on Another Table's Values to Match to Column Name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes, df_stats and df_ratings.

df_stats looks like this

|  | Fruit | Rating_Threshold_Low | Rating_Threshold_High |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple | 4 | 7 |
| 2 | Banana | 5 | 9 |
| 3 | Kiwi | 6 | 8 |

df_ratings looks like this (the first column is the `Fruit` and each subsequent column represents a `rating`.

|  | Fruit | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple | 2 | 4 | 7 | 13 | 2 | 0 | 16 | 1 | 9 | 22 |
| 2 | Banana | 6 | 4 | 2 | 1 | 8 | 7 | 5 | 3 | 9 | 0 |
| 3 | Kiwi | 21 | 4 | 3 | 6 | 8 | 9 | 9 | 8 | 7 | 5 |

What my goal is to get the sum of each the number of ratings within the rating threshold for each fruit (each fruit's rating threshold is different).
In other words, I want to add the column, Rating_Threshold_Sum in `df_stats`, which computes the sum of the ratings within the threshold `df_ratings`. For example, for `Apple`, the Rating threshold is between 4 and 7 (inclusive), so the `Rating_Threshold_Sum` would be 13+2+0+16 = 31.

So as a result, `df_stats` would have the `Ratings_Threshold_Sum` column:

|  | Fruit | Rating_Threshold_Low | Rating_Threshold_High | Rating_Threshold_Sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple | 4 | 7 | 31 |
| 2 | Banana | 5 | 9 | 32 |
| 3 | Kiwi | 6 | 8 | 26 |

I am not sure how to exactly do that, I know that I may have to use df.apply with a custom function, or looping through each row, but aside from that, I'm not sure the best way to tackle this problem. Any advice / direction would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
sums = []
for i in range(len(df_stats)):
   min_v, max_v = df_stats["Rating_Threshold_Low"].values()[i], df_stats["Rating_Threshold_High"].values()[i]  
   values = []
   for z in range(min_v, max_v+1):
      x = df_ratings[str(z)][i]
      values.append(x)
   sums.append(sum(values))
df_stats["Rating_Threshold_Sum"] = sums
```

This is really complicated and there is probably a better way to do it but it should work.